# BASH: How to set variables first when using optargs?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a BASH script which uses optargs. A couple of my flags are used to set variables. Is there a way to force my script to set those variables before following running other functions?

For example my flags `-b` `-r` `-t` require arguments to set variables. Another of my flags, `-a` is dependent on those variables being set. When I call my script `./myscript.sh -a -b foo -r bar -t foobar`, the function triggered by `-a` can't access the variables that were set. When I do `./myscript.sh -b foo -r bar -t foobar -a`, the triggered function can access the variables.

As reference, my WIP code so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -a        = run all functions
# -c        = checkout only
# -p        = pull only
# -x        = checkout, pull, mvn clean install
# -m        = mvn clean install only
# -t        = top level directory of your projects
# -r        = path to coreRepos.txt
# -b        = branch name to check out
#

BRANCH=""
BASEDIR=""
COREREPOS=""
allFunctions() { 
    echo "In all"
    checkPull
    maven

    echo "$BRANCH $BASEDIR $COREREPOS"
    return
  }
checkout() { 
    echo "In checkout" 
    return
}
pull() { 
    echo "In pull" 
    return
}
checkPull() { 
    echo "In checkPull" 
    checkout
    pull
    return
}
maven() { 
    echo "In maven" 
    return
}



while getopts ":acpxmht:r:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in

    b)
        echo "-branch set as: $OPTARG"
        BRANCH=$OPTARG
        export BRANCH
        echo "Echoing $BRANCH"
        ;;
    t)
        echo "-t set as: $OPTARG"
        BASEDIR=$OPTARG
        export BASEDIR
        ;;
    r)
        echo "-r set as: $OPTARG"
        COREREPOS=$OPTARG
        export COREREPOS
        ;;  
    a)
        echo "-all triggered"
        allFunctions
        exit
        ;;
    c)
        echo "-check triggered"
        ;;
    p)
        echo "-pull triggered"
        ;;
    x)
        echo "-check-pull triggered"
        ;;
    m)
        echo "-maven-only triggered"
        ;;
    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    h)
        echo "Help invoked..."
        exit 0
        ;;
  esac
done


exit 0
```

Comment: Don't do any real work when processing the options. Simply record that each option was seen (along with any argument provided by the option). Once all the options are parsed, you can go back and do any necessary post-processing.

Comment: BTW, do you actually need the `export`s here? Promoting shell variables to the environment uses the same region of memory that's used to store command-line arguments, shortening the maximum command-line-length of all children of this script. It's best avoided when not necessary. (And on a related note -- all-caps variable names are [reserved](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) for variables meaningful to the shell or OS; lowercase names should be used to avoid potential conflicts or incompatibilities).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll change the case when I revisit this. The export is there because one of my functions is going to use a complex subshell command and that was the easiest way I found to pass in the values I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing command line options, do as little work as possible. Just record which options were passed, along with any arguments. Once you are done, you can take any actions requested by the arguments. This gives you complete control over *when* things happen. Not only does it ensure that `BRANCH` is set before a function requiring it is called, but it lets you avoid calling `check` unnecessarily before calling `allActions` should the command line look like `myscript.sh -c -a`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# -a        = run all functions
# -c        = checkout only
# -p        = pull only
# -x        = checkout, pull, mvn clean install
# -m        = mvn clean install only
# -t        = top level directory of your projects
# -r        = path to coreRepos.txt
# -b        = branch name to check out
#

BRANCH=""
BASEDIR=""
COREREPOS=""
allFunctions() { 
    echo "In all"
    checkPull
    maven

    echo "$BRANCH $BASEDIR $COREREPOS"
    return
}
checkout() { 
    echo "In checkout" 
    return
}
pull() { 
    echo "In pull" 
    return
}
checkPull() { 
    echo "In checkPull" 
    checkout
    pull
    return
}
maven() { 
    echo "In maven" 
    return
}



while getopts ":acpxmht:r:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in

    b)
        echo "-branch set as: $OPTARG"
        BRANCH=$OPTARG
        export BRANCH
        echo "Echoing $BRANCH"
        ;;
    t)
        echo "-t set as: $OPTARG"
        BASEDIR=$OPTARG
        export BASEDIR
        ;;
    r)
        echo "-r set as: $OPTARG"
        COREREPOS=$OPTARG
        export COREREPOS
        ;;  
    a)
        echo "-all triggered"
        doAll=1
        ;;
    c)
        echo "-check triggered"
        doCheck=1
        ;;
    p)
        echo "-pull triggered"
        doPull=1
        ;;
    x)
        echo "-check-pull triggered"
        doCheckPull=1
        ;;
    m)
        echo "-maven-only triggered"
        doMaven=1
        ;;
    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    h)
        echo "Help invoked..."
        exit 0
        ;;
  esac
done

if [[ $doAll = 1 ]]; then
    allFunctions
    exit 0
fi

if [[ $doCheck = 1 ]]; then
    checkout
fi

if [[ $doPull = 1 ]]; then
    pull
fi

if [[ $doCheckPull = 1 ]]; then
    checkPull
fi

# etc


exit 0
```

Comment: I'd be a bit tempted to reformulate for terseness here. `[[ $doPull = 1 ]] && pull` is certainly shorter, and using less vertical space for the actual action triggers makes them easier to visually compare to each other.

Comment: Sure. I put very little thought into how to record option usage and how to act on that information for this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
root_hash() {
    echo -e $ROOTARG
}
user_hash() {
    echo -e $USERARG
}

while getopts "u:h:r:" Blah; do
  case "$Blah" in
    u)  USERARG=$OPTARG
        export USERARG
        user_hash
        ;;
    r)  ROOTARG=$OPTARG
        export ROOTARG
        root_hash
        ;;
    h)  help
        ;;
    ?)  help
    
  esac
done
shift "$(($OPTIND -1))"
```